How SharePoint generate automatic indexes
I have created a custom SharePoint online list, and I did couple of sorts inside my list views, where all the fields I made sort on them get added as automatic indexes inside the list. So will automatic indexing consider the sort we do inside power apps, power automate, SharePoint rest Api and graph Api? or it only consider the sort we do inside the list view?
Thanks

I don't think SharePoint will add indexes automatically when you sort inside Power Apps, Power Automate, SharePoint REST API or Graph API.
